# 400 Bad Request Error When trying to Pass object with image to Server

Tags: angular, rest, typescript, aspnetboilerplate

In my application, I am trying to pass an object that contains an image to the web api but it throws a 400 bad request error and picks out the `scanImage` property as the culprit. I have tried so many workarounds and googled a lot but no help found yet.

**DTO**

```
    public class CreateTaxMapDto
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Tax Type is required")]
        public int TaxTypeId { get; set; }

        public int? BranchId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Date of receipt is required")]
        public DateTime DateOfReceipt { get; set; }

        public decimal Amount { get; set; }

        public IFormFile ScanImage { get; set; }

        [StringLength(150)]
        public string Remark { get; set; }
    }
```

**ApplicationService**

```
        public async Task SaveTax(CreateTaxMapDto input)
        {
            // Code to save the input to the database
        }
```

**CreateTaxMap.ts**

```
export class CreateTaxMapDto {
    taxTypeId: number;
    branchId: number;
    dateOfReceipt: Date;
    amount: number;
    scanImage: any;
    constructor(data?: any) {
        if (data !== undefined) {
            this.taxTypeId = data['taxTypeId'] !== undefined ? data['taxTypeId'] : null;
            this.branchId = data['branchId'] !== undefined ? data['branchId'] : null;
            this.dateOfReceipt = data['dateOfReceipt'] !== undefined ? data['dateOfReceipt'] : null;
            this.amount = data['amount'] !== undefined ? data['amount'] : null;
            this.scanImage = data['scanImage'] !== undefined ? data['scanImage'] : null;
        }
    }

    static fromJS(data: any): CreateTaxMapDto {
        return new CreateTaxMapDto(data);
    }

    toJS(data?: any) {
        data = data === undefined ? {} : data;
        data['taxTypeId'] = this.taxTypeId !== undefined ? this.taxTypeId : null;
        data['branchId'] = this.branchId !== undefined ? this.branchId : null;
        data['dateOfReceipt'] = this.dateOfReceipt !== undefined ? this.dateOfReceipt : null;
        data['amount'] = this.amount !== undefined ? this.amount : null;
        data['scanImage'] = this.scanImage !== undefined ? this.scanImage : null;

        return data;
    }

    toJSON() {
        return JSON.stringify(this.toJS());
    }

clone() {
    const json = this.toJSON();
    return new CreateTaxMapDto(JSON.parse(json));
}
```

}

**Create-Tax.Component.Html**

```
<input #imageInput type="file" class="form-control" (change)="onImageChange()" />
```

**Component.ts**

```
  onImageChange() {
    let imgInput = this.imageInput.nativeElement;
    if (imgInput.files && imgInput.files[0]) {
      this.file = imgInput.files[0];
    }
  }

save(): void {
    this.saving = true;
    this.tax.branchId = this.appSession.user.branchId;
    const custFile = <MyFile>(this.file); // MyFile is an interface that extends File
    let originalFile = {
      'lastModified': custFile.lastModified,
      'lastModifiedDate': custFile.lastModifiedDate,
      'name': custFile.name,
      'size': custFile.size,
      'type': custFile.type,
      'webkitRelativePath': custFile.webkitRelativePath
    };
    this.tax.scanImage = originalFile;
    console.log(this.tax.scanImage);
    this._taxService.create(this.tax)
        .finally(() => { this.saving = false; })
        .subscribe(() => {
            this.notify.success(this.l('SavedSuccessfully'), 'Tax Saved');
            this.close();
            this.modalSave.emit(null);
        });
  }
```

**Service.ts**

```
create(input: CreateTaxMapDto): Observable<TaxDto> {
        let url_ = this.baseUrl + '/api/services/app/Tax/SaveTax';

        const content_ = JSON.stringify(input ? input.toJS() : null);
        console.log('Inputt: ' + content_);

        return this.http.request(url_, {
            body: content_,
            method: 'post',
            headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                'Accept': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
            })
        }).map((response) => {
            return this.processCreate(response);
        }).catch((response: any, caught: any) => {
            if (response instanceof Response) {
                try {
                    return Observable.of(this.processCreate(response));
                } catch (e) {
                    return <Observable<TaxDto>><any>Observable.throw(e);
                }
            } else
                return <Observable<TaxDto>><any>Observable.throw(response);
        });
    }
```

The error on the console is as follows

```
> {code: 0, message: "Your request is not valid!", details: "The
> following errors were detected during validation. ↵ -  ↵",
> validationErrors: Array(1)} code : 0 details : "The following errors
> were detected during validation. ↵ -  ↵" message : "Your request is
> not valid!" validationErrors : Array(1) 0 : members : ["scanImage"]
> message : ""
> __proto__ : Object length : 1
> __proto__ : Array(0)
> __proto__ : Object
```

Iam using aspnetboilerplate v3.0.0 .NET Core + Angular4. Please help me. I have been on this for days now.

Comment: Okay, since you are using `JSON.stringify` instead of `multipart` form, it won't bind to `IFormFile`. You should convert and send it as base64 string.

Comment: @aaron okay before you responded, I thought of trying converting to bytes or uint8Array in typescript. What do you think?

Comment: You probably still need a base64 string for `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: Okay. Let me try that out. I'll call your attention if I still need help.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to create a controller based on AbpController.
Then upload your image via this controller and return the image unique filename. Then use that unique filename in CreateTaxMapDto.

Ref => [Uploading Image in Aspnet boilerplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47259324/uploading-image-in-aspnet-boilerplate)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried Aaron's suggestion and it worked for me. What I did was to convert the file to base64string on the client, passed it to the web api and converted the string to bytes and saved.

Comment: yeah it's another solution ;)